# How to keep numbers and remove chars from varchar column in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I need to keep numbers and remove chars from varchar column in snowflake .

need new col just in ::numbers from existing column as varchar.

Comment: Could you please add some sample data to your question, and what have you tried already?

Comment: Have you thought of using [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr) for this?

Comment: `select regexp_replace ('abc123','[^0-9]','')` replaced --> Use this

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  existing_col, 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(existing_col, '[^0-9]', '') AS new_col 
FROM my_table;
```